# Setting WebRTC audio media constraints in libjingle_peerconnection to disable audio processing

Tags: webrtc, libjingle

Is it possible to disable all audio processing with the API provided by libjingle?

I'm trying to set media constraints for an audio stream using the libjingle_peerconnection CocoaPod on OS X. These are constraints that would normally be passed to `getUserMedia()` in JavaScript. My goal is to set several parameters to `false` to essentially disable all audio processing.

```
    let audioPairs = [
        RTCPair(key: "echoCancellation", value: "false"),
        RTCPair(key: "googEchoCancellation", value: "false"),
        RTCPair(key: "googEchoCancellation2", value: "false"),
        RTCPair(key: "googAutoGainControl", value: "false"),
        RTCPair(key: "googAutoGainControl2", value: "false"),
        RTCPair(key: "googNoiseSuppression", value: "false"),
        RTCPair(key: "googHighpassFilter", value: "false"),
        RTCPair(key: "googTypingNoiseDetection", value: "false"),
        RTCPair(key: "googAudioMirroring", value: "false")
    ]

    let audioConstraints = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: [RTCPair](), optionalConstraints: audioPairs)
```

I tried:

1. Passing the constraints into `RTCPeerConnectionFactory.peerConnectionWithICEServers(_, constraints, delegate)`
2. Passing the constraints into `RTCPeerConnection.createAnswerWithDelegate(_, constraints)`

However, none of the constraints are being honored. Audio processing still occurs. Making the constraints mandatory causes failures during the answer/offer handshake (since they are not allowed as mandatory parameters).

I feel like I should be passing these constraints into something like `RTCPeerConnectionFactory.mediaStreamWithLabel(_)` or `RTCPeerConnectionFactory.audioTrackWithID(_)`, but there is no API for passing in constraints at this point. There was once a method called `RTCPeerConnection.addStream(_, constraints)`, but the constraints arguments has been removed.

Comment: I doubt RTCPeerConnection has anything to do with audio processing. There used to be something confusingly called "mediaConstraints" in RTCPeerConnection, which has since been renamed [RTCOfferOptions](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-RTCOfferOptions) because they were just poorly named settings that had nothing to do with constraints from getUserMedia.

Comment: @jib Thanks for responding. I agree, and I think that's why I'm confused. Sometimes RTCMediaConstraints has to do with the answer/offer (e.g. createOffer or createAnswer in JS), and sometimes it's used for the getUserMedia-style constraints.